# Событие изменения коллекции дочерних элементов контрола

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть некий контрол-контейнер. (В моём случае это `InkCanvas`) У него соответственно есть коллекция дочерних элементов (`InkCanvas.Children`).

И эта коллекция изменяется в коде который я не контролирую (контрол определён в моей dll, а добавление/удаление элементов происходит в коде который использует мою dll)

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность получать уведомления о изменении коллекции? Если да, то как?

Comment: А зачем вам следить за контролом? Логика должна быть в VM, а не View.

Comment: Чтобы по факту изменения кол-ва дочерних элементов производить определённую обработку и переучёт всех текущих элементов коллекции. Я бы и рад (и от части так и есть) логику добавления в VM реализовать с соответствующими действиями. Но канва в режиме редактирования поддерживает горячие клавиши копирования/удаления элементов и ни коим образом не уведомляет об их применении... в этом то как раз и проблема.... Канва в данном случае выбрана как почти готовый визуальный редактор дабы сэкономить время на разработку. Но видимо придётся пилить свой вариант редактора с нуля.

Comment: Хм, это подлость со стороны InkCanvas, конечно.

Comment: Подождите, а как насчёт этого: http://stackoverflow.com/a/729052/276994?

Comment: Да, был уже вариант сделать привязку к коллекции элементов. Но InkCanvas не даёт сделать привязку данных к Child в коде.

Comment: А зачем Child, вам же нужно `Strokes`? Что не сработало из того решения?

Comment: Мне сейчас нужен именно Childs (коллекция дочерних элементов) В перспективе скорее всего понадобится и Strokes тоже.

Comment: А не сработала из того примера именно привязка т.к. у InkCanvas InkCanvas.StrokesProperty есть. А что-нибудь на подобие InkCanvas.ChildsCollectionProperty нет.

Comment: Хм, а вам нужны реально `Children`? Чего нет в `Strokes` из того, что вам реально нужно?

Comment: В Strokes записываются все рисованые на канве элементы. А в Children добавленные дочерние контролы типа textBox, image и т.д. Мне в первую очередь они и нужны.

Comment: Ну, а дочерние элементы разве тоже возникают сами по себе?

Comment: Не, возникновение (добавление) я как раз таки контролирую. И с этим проблем нет. А вот удаление по нажатию Del и ctrl-c->ctrl-v нет....

Comment: Ээээ... Элементы, которые добавили вы вручную, удаляются без code-behind? o_O Вы уверены?

Comment: Кейс: юзер жмёт кнопку "добавить"  которая завязана на мою команду в которой происходит добавление контрола на канву и пр. действия которые мне нужны. После чего юзер выбирает добавленный элемент (я могу подписаться на событие изменения  выбора) и жмёт del. И элемент удаляется.... И вот об этом канва никак не уведомляет... сейчас правда пришла в голову мысль, что после удаления по идее должно отработать событие изменения выбора. Теоретически в нём можно проверять а не пропали ли какие элементы. Но это, как по мне, всё же костыль...

Comment: Что-то не то, можете соорудить пример? У меня вот такой XAML: `<InkCanvas><Button>Delete me</Button></InkCanvas>`, я выделяю кнопку и нажимаю Del, ничего не происходит.

Comment: Получится если в разметке канвы прописать  EditingMode="Select". И да, косвенно по событию изменения выделения можно в том числе узнавать о том что какие-то объекты были удалены т.к. событие отрабатывает и при удалении выделенного объекта. Походу это единственный вариант своевременно обнаруживать удаления...

Comment: Окей, теперь понятно. Написал вариант в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, вот вам ещё один вариант.

Если у вас внутренние элементы известны заранее, подпишитесь на событие `Unloaded` у них:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement child in IC.Children)
    child.Unloaded += (sender, args) => OnChildRemoved(child);

// ...
void OnChildRemoved(FrameworkElement child)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Removed");
}
```

Если вы добавляете child-элемент вручную, в этот момент можно подписаться на его `Unloaded`.

Answer (score 2):

Проверяете `Children` на реализацию `INotifyCollectionChanged` и цепляетесь к событию `CollectionChanged`, если реализует.

Это стандартное поведение для WPF.

Минимальная реализация наверно как то так будет выглядеть:

```
private IEnumerable children;

public IEnumerable Children
{
  get { return children; }
  set
  {
    var notified = children as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (notified != null)
      notified.CollectionChanged -= NotifiedOnCollectionChanged;

    children = value;

    notified = children as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (notified != null)
      notified.CollectionChanged += NotifiedOnCollectionChanged;
  }
}

private void NotifiedOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что практически у всех стандартных WPF контролов-контейнеров дочерние элементы хранятся в UIElementCollection и он не реализует INotifyCollectionChanged. Если бы у данной коллекции элементов был реализовано хоть какое-нибудь событие дающее понять что что-то изменилось - вопрос который я тут задал не возник бы....

Comment: @Alexey а, ну тогда можно вот такое решение, оно вполне закрывает ваш кейс - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45d45739-75d3-4ef3-8a40-76b68cde4115/binding-to-inkcanvas-children?forum=wpf

Comment: Создавать класс наследник от InkCanvas реализующий необходимое мне поведение тоже не вариант.